# Free Compositing video tutorials in blender

Tags: compositing-nodes

Where can I get indepth tutorials about compositing in blender for Free? Any channel I can get such videos about compositing in blender?

Comment: You can see some tutorials on YouTube in which there is wide use of compositing . These are some examples Blender guru earth tutorial
https://youtu.be/9Q8PwcDzb8Y CG geek city tutorial https://youtu.be/i4ySFm4ey9U

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/what-is-the-proper-action-for-a-question-that-requests-links-to-tutorials